In C, Are Function Calls Resolved During Compile Time?
I'm referring to stuff like passing arguments to the function, making sure that the function declaration matches with all other calls of the function, and everything before actually executing the function. All of that is done during compile time yes?
I tried looking it up on the web, but none of my sources were clear on telling me what exactly the compiler does with the function, its definition, calls, and prototypes during runtime in C.

Uh, yes they are. You have var-args functions, which are flexibile w.r.t. parameters; and also, you can under-define a function int foo( ) and then you can pass whatever you like, but other than that - yeah. Haven't you run a compiler with some mismatched function calls to check?

Yeah, the compiler always gives me warnings. So then the function is executed during run time?

@einpoklum I believe under-defined functions are going away in the next C standard.

@Barmar: They're effectively gone away for 30 years already, if you want to be serious about the code you're writing :-)

@einpoklum Someone posted some AI-derived code yesterday, and it used a K&R-style function heading.

@Barmar Concerning "under-defined functions are going away ", With C2X allowing int f(...), looks like a substitute for some aspects of int f().

@chux-ReinstateMonica Right. AIUI, what they're doing is making f() equivalent to f(void), like C++.

Yes. The level of C language is a bit higher than Assembler. So the functions are actually the subroutines, and their arguments generally pass through the hardware stack and have compile-time defined positions in this stack.


I'm referring to stuff like passing arguments to the function, making sure that the function declaration matches with all other calls of the function, and everything before actually executing the function. All of that is done during compile time yes?

It is complicated.
There are two levels to the C standard. One, it is specified in terms of an abstract computer. In this model, the source code is translated to another form in one phase, and it is executed in a later phase. Checks for matching declarations are performed, to the extent they can be, in the translation phase. Preparing arguments is done in the execution phase.
Two, the C standard allows implementations to optimize in many ways—in any way that produces, for a well-defined program, a result with the same output, input/output interactions, and accesses of volatile objects as the program would produce in some implementation in the abstract model.

I'm referring to stuff like passing arguments to the function,…

Because a compiler can optimize, it is allowed to call a function, or emulate a call to a function, while it is translating the program, if it is able to figure out the results the function would have. It is also allowed to replace a function call with instructions inside the calling routine, so that the same result is computed but the function is never actually called.

… making sure that the function declaration matches with all other calls of the function,…

Compilers do checking for constraint violations in function declarations, but only for the declarations they can see during compilation. So if a source file both defines a function and includes a header that declares the function, it can check those declarations with each other. However, if one source file defines a function and another source file declares the function, and there is no common header between them, the compiler cannot check the declarations with each other.

… and everything before actually executing the function.

If a function is declared with a prototype, the compiler can check arguments in a function call to ensure they match the parameter types, including converting them to the parameter types if suitable.
If a function is declared without a prototype, the actual argument types are not known to the compiler (unless another declaration with a prototype is visible), and the compiler cannot check the argument types.

All of that is done during compile time yes?

Most C implementations use compilation and check types during compilation. The C standard allows C to be implemented in other ways, including run-time interpretation.

"If a function is declared with a prototype, the compiler can check arguments in a function call to ensure they match the parameter types" -- special note that the prototype can be wrong (different number of parameters, different types, different calling convention or different return type), type checking can be done and pass, and the end result can still be unexpected.
